# UEFI, Windows 8 - installing SSD, removing HDD

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, ssd

I have a perfectly good laptop for work, HP ProBook 455 G1, the only problem is it's really a garbage HDD_! So I decided to buy an SSD. But, the problem is that this machine has to be fully functional every day.

My question is: can I just buy an SSD, put it in in place of the original HDD, install Windows 8.1 on it (I have a DVD, and yes, the notebook still has a DVD drive :) ) and if something unexpected happens, just pop in the old drive and at least have it running for the time being?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any reason you can't do what you describe.  I do that routinely  myself on my own machines.

Comment: Oh, thank you for your swift answer! My concern was as follows: I know very little about UEFI and haven't really got time to study it in depth. Good old BIOS wouldn't give a damn, but with UEFI it might be different, I thought. If it's all fine like you say, I'm gonna run to the store and get me some SSD action :)

Comment: If you want to get fancy you could clone the HDD to the SSD and it's like nothing happened to your data.

Comment: I actually want a clean install, and a lot of data on that old drive is pure trash. I'm thinking about 120GB drive, which is enough. What I am confused about are the MLC, TLC, SLC and those different writing speeds. I mean, the cheapo SSD writes (sequentially, big files) 450 MB/s, but the twice as expensive drive does only 135 MB/s. How is that possible?

Comment: The larger the SSD the longer the lifespan in general it will have.  Has nothing to do with the size specifically more about how newer devices are simply larger and use better technology.  When you fall below 256 GB you are looking at the 2 or 3 generation old SSD devices.

Comment: @iSS: That is a separate question and the answer is part of the confusion is 1. technology and 2. **marketing**.

Comment: Yeah, I work in marketing, I understand that you have to sell stuff somehow. But in case of SSDs, the parameters are made in a very confusing fashion. Say it's SuperLightFastSpeedPlus and the ordinary person will buy it. I like Apple's approach: expensive, but clear and working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, This will work fine, Obviously any files you create on the SSD will not be copied over when you put the HDD back in so an idea to get around this is to use cloud storage like Dropbox or Google Drive.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, data would have to be copied, I have a lot of spare drives coming from those notebooks made in an "unfortunate" fashion :)

Comment: As my best friend said to me a number of times: Buy Apple. End of trouble.